# Auto run a script on start of a computer by connecting other local machine on local network

Tags: ubuntu-16.04

I want to run a set of commands on start of my machine which requires password input as well to connect to other machine on local network.

My Commands:

**1) ssh userName@IPADDRESS**

**2) cd /var/www/html**

**3) cd Proj name**

First command requires password on execution.

OS Version: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

I have tried various script but none was useful for connecting in other machine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to run a script during booting in a remote machine?

Comment: No on my machine after I start my machine

Answer (score 2):

Already tried this?

```
   #!/usr/bin/expect -f
    spawn ssh user@hostname
    expect "password:"
    sleep 1
    send "<your password>\r"
    command1
    command2
```

and do you want that this script auto runs on your PC or on the Server?

However:

> 1. If you want that it starts on your PC when the Server starts, then write a script that checks every minute if the server runs, and when
>      the server runs execute that code above.
> 2. you want that the script runs on the machine at startup, just use crontab.
> 3. you want that it runs on your PC at your PC's startup, just use crontab.

Comment: use sshpass, `sshpass -p "password" ssh user@hostname`

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

- Put the command in your crontab file. Make sure to edit the cron job
  for the root user, Command is sudo crontab -e.
- `@reboot yourscript.`
- Put a yourscript under the /etc/init.d directory, Change the
  yourscript permissions(to make it executable) of the script.